# I am trying to Schedule Class that will add a new contact under Account every 2 min

Tags: apex, community, scheduled-apex, asyncapexjob

I am trying to Schedule Class that will add a new contact under All Account every 2 min and also there should be a validation check that you can not have more than `05 Contacts` under a single Account.

`Updated`

The Code I've written is working and creating a new Contact for every Account but now i want a Validation Check that will check weather Account has less than 5 Contact or not

I've tried with `accList.Contacts.Size()<=5` but this is giving me Error `FATAL_ERROR System.AsyncException: The Apex job named "ScheduleContactOnAccountEveryTenMin 2019-08-07 15:24:07" is already scheduled for execution.`

Thanks

```
global class ScheduleContactOnAccountEveryTenMin implements schedulable
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext scx)
    {
        List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate > 2019-07-26T13:10:24.000+0000];
        List<Contact> conList2 = new List<Contact>();

        for(Account accSobj2 : accList)
        {
            Contact conS = new Contact();
            conS.FirstName = 'Schedule Class';
            conS.LastName = ' Test';
            conS.AccountId = accSobj2.Id;
            conList2.add(conS);
        }

        // if(conList2.size()<=5){

        Insert conList2;
        ScheduleContactOnAccountEveryTenMin.start();
        // abort Job and start again
        System.abortJob( scx.getTriggerId() );

        /*}
        else
        {
            System.abortJob( scx.getTriggerId() );
        }*/

    }
    public static void start()
    {
        // start keepalive again in 5 mins
        Datetime sysTime = System.now().addSeconds( 120 );  
        String chronExpression = '' + sysTime.second() + ' ' + sysTime.minute() + ' ' + sysTime.hour() + ' ' + sysTime.day() + ' ' + sysTime.month() + ' ? ' + sysTime.year();
        System.schedule( 'ScheduleContactOnAccountEveryTenMin ' + sysTime, chronExpression, new ScheduleContactOnAccountEveryTenMin() );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you please mention that.

Comment: I am not getting any Error, but Job is also not getting created

Comment: Is there anything on debug log?
Please note that scheduler class fails if the record size is more than 50k.
I would suggest to use Batch class and use Schedule class to schedule the batch job.

Comment: What is the business need leading to this implementation?

Comment: I am implementing this to get more knowledge about Asynchronous Apex, I've recently started Asynchronous Apex

Comment: Can you please put 'Limit' on your SOQL query and try.

Comment: Problem is not with SOQL Limit as there are only 5 Accounts..
Problem is how can i create contact with every Account as ```conS.AccountId = accId;``` Here i am assigning Set to Id which is not possible so i am finding other solution for this

Comment: @Dave: Can you please update the question with final code which is not working and also mention where you are changing Set to Id.

Comment: @maniac coder: I've modified above Code and Error description. Can you please check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, this is not an ideal test of your Anonymous Apex skills because it does not represent the kind of business functionality you're likely to build using those features. That said:

```
    // if(conList2.size()<=5){
```

This conditional is in the wrong place. If you don't want to add more than five total Contacts on any Account, you need to query for the Contacts associated with each Account and then check the size of that list before you add more. You do this using a subquery:

```
    List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate > 2019-07-26T13:10:24.000+0000];
    List<Contact> conList2 = new List<Contact>();

    for(Account accSobj2 : accList)
    {
        if (accSobj2.Contacts.size() < 5) {
```

Next, you're aborting your current scheduled job *after* you try to schedule a new one, which is what produces the error

> System.AsyncException: The Apex job named "ScheduleContactOnAccountEveryTenMin 2019-08-07 15:24:07" is already scheduled for execution

You need to do the abort *before* you call `start()`.

Lastly, this type of functionality - which runs broadly across an sObject query likely to return a large number of results - in production should be implemented as Batch Apex. The inherent asynchrony of Batch Apex and its dependency on platform load and queue behavior would likely not permit you to run it every two minutes, something the platform generally doesn't support with that level of precision anyway.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed: I was doing ```if (accSobj2.Contacts.size() < 5)``` after Inserting the Contact. -- My bad

And Thanks for clarifying Error ```System.AsyncException: The Apex job named " " is already scheduled for execution```

and for last comment - as I was getting in more depth of Schedule Apex(What can we do with Schedule Apex). I will keep in mind that in these type of scenario i've to implement Batch Apex

I will also try this to implement with Batch Apex also to understand Batch Apex

At last ```Thanks Again for clearing my doubts``` Have a great day!!